# Redirect Website if its not specified domain in script - Protection using Javascript

Tags: javascript, security, multiple-domains, redirect

**Brief Idea:** I am building script for protecting my webdesign work by locking them on Single domain. If website is uploaded on different domain, It will redirect to my website. Means it won't allow to load actual website from different domain except I specify them.

My Working Script:

```
-- DECODED SCRIPT --

[]['constructor']['constructor'](self['unescape']('if(~location.protocol.indexOf('http:')&&~location.host.indexOf('isupportu.in')){}else(location.href='http://iamwebdeveloper.in')'))()
```

Here on above code, I am allowing my work to load on "www.abc.com" with http protocol only.
However it won't work if we load website without www i.e. "abc.com".

```
www.abc.com --> Website load

abc.com --> www.iamwebdeveloper.in

xyz.com --> www.iamwebdeveloper.in

www.xyz.com --> www.iamwebdeveloper.in
```

I decided to use `.htaccess` / `web.config` file to force redirect domain without www. request to www.abc.com [which is working very well]

**But now I want to upgrade this script and I need your help:**

- Don't want dependency on .htaccess / web.config file for redirecting non www. request.
- www. and non www request should accept, but no subdomain allow. For e.g. subdomain.abc.com is not allowed.
- I want to add multiple domains in script for big clients who has multiple domain for their single website as Addon domain. I want to add more domain in above script.

Can someone help me to validate this script for my above logic ?

```
[]["constructor"]["constructor"]
(
    self["unescape"]
    ("<!-- I WILL USE THIS CODE AFTER CONVERTING TO ESCAPE TEXT AND IGNORE THIS COMMENT -->
        if (location.protocol.indexOf("http:") && ( (location.host.indexOf("isupportu.in")) || (location.host.indexOf("paytronicindia.com")) || (location.host.indexOf("paytronicworldwide.com")) || (location.host.indexOf("paytronicnetwork.com")) )
        ){}else(location.href='http://iamwebdeveloper.in')
    ")
)
()
```

Comment: Well, if someone got hold of your work (code and all) and knew this protection code exists, they'd just remove that code and get away with it. Pretty useless I'm afraid.

Comment: I am agree with you but I am injecting this code in multiple javascript include in jquery script and encrypting all js. Nothing is foolproof protection but at least we can slow them.

Comment: You seem to have a misunderstanding of the purpose of SO..  We help you with a specific problem, we do not code entire programs for you.

Comment: Hi.. I am not asking for ready made code. I can code by myself. But I want your help to build logic with example. I wrote all this to make you all understand my purpose. And this will help other developer too.

Comment: You have a task for us.. that is not the purpose of SO..  Even if it isn't ready-made code, you're still asking us to do something for you(even if not directly, for example if we were to help you in such a task).  That is not the purpose of SO..  We help you with existing, specific problems in existing code..

Comment: Dear All, I always found many solutions in SO... And this is my first post / question. I may be wrong in writing this post. But my intention was just to get help from your to check my code for syntax error or logic error. I still not received any answers for my query. I request you all to correct me if I am wrong in anything. Thank you!

Comment: There are obvious syntax errors in your code (unescaped single quotes in a single-quoted string), but those are present in your "working script" too, so I assume they're just the result of incorrect de-obfuscation. They do mean that nobody else can really test your code as you've shown it, since it's not a valid [short, self-contained correct example](http://sscce.org). Anyway, I assume you've tested it yourself: what happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your *real* question is something like "*How can I check in JavaScript whether the hostname of the current page is one of a specific list of domains, with or without a `www.` prefix?*"

There are many ways to do that, but one fairly simple one would be to match a [regexp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) against [`location.hostname`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location):

```javascript
var re = /^(www\.)?((site1|site2|site3)\.in|(site4|site5)\.com)$/;
if ( !re.test( location.hostname ) ) {
    location.href = 'http://yourwebsite.in';
}
```

Obfuscating that is left as an exercise.